# VMware ESXi 5.1 - isolinux.cfg - Boot from SAN LUN?

Tags: linux, redhat, vmware-esxi, syslinux

I've created a custom scripted install disc for VMware ESXi 5.1 U1. I am trying to have an option (default) to boot to local disk or in my case LUN 0 that is presented from the SAN. The Hypervisor is installed to LUN 0 which is attached via Fibre Channel and is booting from the SAN.

I thought that the 'Boot from local disk' would allow me to boot to the installation on the Boot to SAN LUN but that is not true.

Is there a way to instruct syslinux to boot to the first available LUN instead of local disk? Currently, the process loops because there is no true local disk available.

Below is a copy of isolinux.cfg

```
DEFAULT menu.c32
MENU TITLE HP-ESXi-5.1.0-std-iso Boot Menu
NOHALT 1
PROMPT 0
TIMEOUT 450
LABEL hddboot
  LOCALBOOT 0x80
  MENU LABEL Boot from local disk
LABEL install
  KERNEL mboot.c32
  APPEND -c boot.cfg
  MENU LABEL HP-ESXi-5.1.0-std-iso Installer
LABEL swboot1
  KERNEL mboot.c32
  APPEND -c swboot1.cfg
  MENU LABEL SW (Local Disk) HP-ESXi-5.1.0-std-iso Scripted Installer
LABEL swboot2
  KERNEL mboot.c32
  APPEND -c swboot2.cfg
  MENU LABEL ^SW (Boot-From-SAN) HP-ESXi-5.1.0-std-iso Scripted Installer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your SAN LUN is the next device in the system's boot order after the install CD, then this should do it:

```
LOCALBOOT -1
```

This causes ISOLINUX to report that it's failed to boot, causing the next device in the boot order to be used instead.